# htaccess redirect of different add-on domains to folders which are associated to each domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We tried various htaccess rewrite rules but could not get to work what we need to do. Maybe some advise here?

Assume we have a main domain (`a.com`) with 2 add-on domains (`b.com` and `c.com`), all pointing to the website root.

Then we have folders, all in root, like `/folder_a1`, `/folder_a2`, `/folder_a3`,`/folder_b1`,`/folder_b2`,`/folder_b3` and `/folder_c1`, `/folder_c2`,`/folder_c3` in which there are php files.

Users shall be able to come to the site via:

URL=`a.com/folder_1/xxx.php` and be redirected to `root/folder_a1` 
URL=`b.com/folder_1/xxx.php` and be redirected to `root/folder_b1` 
URL=`c.com/folder_1/xxx.php` and be redirected to `root/folder_c1`

Each time we want to keep in the browser address bar the URL the user came from (if he came via a.com we want to keep showing a.com... etc.)

In this example we basically have to map the url string `.../folder_1`, dependent on the URL used, either to `folder_a1`, `folder_b1` or `folder_c1`.

We tried (amongst others):

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.a\.com [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^folder1(/.*|)$ /folder_a1$1 [L,NC]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.b\.com [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^folder1(/.*|)$ /folder_b1$1 [L,NC]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.c\.com [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^folder1(/.*|)$ /folder_c1$1 [L,NC]`

But that does not do the trick. With these rules we always and up at `folder_a1`.

Any suggestions how we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution (thanks to the support of our host rochenhost !).

As there was no answer here (yet ;), here is what we found:

The only issue was that we did not repeat the re-write condition before every re-write-rule, which meant that the condition was only applied once, to the first rule, and to none of the following rules.

Once added, all works.

Cheers